# Execute Code When The URL Has Hash OR HASH Changes After Load?

Tags: jquery, window.location, fragment-identifier

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Execute code when a hash exists on load:

```
if(location.hash) { //code; }
```

Execute code when the hash changes:

```
$(window).hashchange(function(){//code;});
```

How do I combine these 2 checks?
This doesn't work:

```
if(location.hash || $(window).hashchange(function() { //code; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function for `theCode`, Pass its reference to `hashchange` event and on page load check if hash exists execute it directly

```
function theCode() { //code; }

if(location.hash){
    theCode();
}

$(window).hashchange(theCode);
```